# CSS ::selection automatically swap color and background-color

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm using the `::selection` CSS construction. Say my text is written in black over a white background, but for some elements which are in written in blue, green or red for instance. I'd like that when selected, the color and background-color of the text are swaped: Normal text wound be white on black, red text would be white on red, etc...

Of course, I know how to do that by putting specific rules for each kind of text I have. But I wonder if there exists a simple way to do this automatically, that is without having to think to all the possible kind of texts I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this automatically: the closest thing we have to taking the specified font color is `background-color: currentColor`, but once you set `color` to any other value, [`currentColor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#currentcolor) will take that new value instead of the original.

Meaning, this rule:

```
::selection {
    background-color: currentColor;
    color: white;
}
```

Will actually set both the text color and the background color to white, because `currentColor` ends up computing to `white`, taking after the `color: white` declaration. This is regardless of whether you put it before or after the `background-color` declaration.

Here's an [interactive fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/X7K8Y) to show you what I mean.